# Count of sampling points within a grid cell

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sf

Calculate the total number of sampling points within each grid cell of a spatial grid.

I would like to make a grid and calculate the total count of sampling points  within  each grid cell.  I created a randomly generated data and grid, and tried to calculate the number of records within a grid cells  using both the sf and raster packages, using previous similar  SO questions, but wthout success. I have also looked into the extract function.  Im fairly new to spatial analysis.

```
 library(sf)
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(mapview)
library(mapedit)

#Trial with sf package 
# load some spatial data. Administrative Boundary
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787313/how-to-create-a-grid-of-       spatial-points
aut <- getData('GADM', country = 'aut', level = 0)
aut <- st_as_sf(aut)
#Try with polygons
grid <- aut %>% 
 st_make_grid(cellsize = 0.5, what = "polygons") %>% 
  st_intersection(aut)                               

#fake data
 lat<-runif(1000, 46.5, 48.5)
 lon<-runif(1000, 13,16)
pos<-data.frame(lat,lon)

 ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = aut) + 
  geom_sf(data = grid)+
geom_point(data=pos, aes(lon, lat)) 
#how to count number of records within each cell?  
 ########################################
#Trial with raster package
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889531/r-how-can-i-count-how-   many-points-are-in-each-cell-of-my-grid
 r<-raster(xmn=13, ymn=46.5, xmx=16, ymx=48.5, res=0.5)
r[] <- 0
#How do I use the pos data here
xy <- spsample(as(extent(r), 'SpatialPolygons'), 100, 'random')
tab <- table(cellFromXY(r, xy))
r[as.numeric(names(tab))] <- tab
plot(r)
points(xy, pch=20)
d <- data.frame(coordinates(r), count=r[])
```

I would like to obtain a table with number of sampling points.

Comment: Have you looked into stat_bin_2d? alternatively stat_hex_bin? these calculate the count and density per bin.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I had not considered  stat_bin_2d or stat_hex_bin. How do you get the count of the bins?  I just started to play with these funcitons but so far not got anything meaningful out of it yet.    ggplot(pos, aes(lon, lat)) +
  geom_bin2d(binwidth = 2) + 
  stat_bin2d(geom = "text", aes(label = ..count..),binwidth = 10)   +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example data

```
library(raster)   
aut <- getData('GADM', country = 'aut', level = 0)
r <- raster(aut, res=0.5)
lat <- runif(1000, 46.5, 48.5)
lon <- runif(1000, 13,16)
# note that you should use (lon, lat), in that order!
pos <- data.frame(lon, lat)
```

Solution

```
r <- rasterize(pos, r, fun="count")
plot(r)
```

To get a table, you can do

```
x <- rasterToPoints(r)
z <- cbind(cell=cellFromXY(r, x[,1:2]), value=x[,3])
head(z)
#     cell value
#[1,]   22    4
#[2,]   23   45
#[3,]   24   36
#[4,]   25   52
#[5,]   26   35
#[6,]   27   38
```

Or, alternatively, `na.omit(cbind(1:ncell(r), values(r)))`

Answer (score 4):

counting the `lengths` of `st_intersects` (note: not `st_intersection`) would give you a vector of points contained in each grid cell:

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(mapview)
library(mapedit)

#Trial with sf package 
# load some spatial data. Administrative Boundary
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787313/how-to-create-a-grid-of-       spatial-points
aut <- getData('GADM', country = 'aut', level = 0)
aut <- st_as_sf(aut)
#Try with polygons
grid <- aut %>% 
  st_make_grid(cellsize = 0.5, what = "polygons") %>% 
  st_intersection(aut)                               

#fake data
lat<-runif(1000, 46.5, 48.5)
lon<-runif(1000, 13,16)
pos<-data.frame(lat,lon)

pos = st_as_sf(pos, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

tab = st_intersects(grid, pos)
lengths(tab)
[1]  0  0  0  0  4 24 23 34 23 13 14  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3 38 40 48 46 47 33  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[33]  0 35 48 51 35 38 44  0  0  0  0 44 43 41 53 44 32  0  0  0  0  8  8 10 12  7  0  0  0  0  0
```

If you then want to bind that to grid as a `sf` object you could do:

```
grid = st_sf(n = lengths(tab), geometry = st_cast(grid, "MULTIPOLYGON"))

mapview(grid, zcol = "n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ggplot(pos, aes(x = lon, y=lat)) + 
geom_bin2d(binwidth = 2) +
stat_bin_2d(aes(label=stat(count)), binwidth=2, geom="text", position="identity") +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could your provide an advice of how to overlay this figure over a map e.g. the map of Austria I provide as an example of.   It a sf object, but it is possible to visialise sf objects with geom_sf.  I have been trying without success.

Comment: I am not familiar with sf objects but whenever I need to plot some spartial data I got to leaflet (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shapes.html)