# R Leaflet. Group point data into cells to summarise many data points

Tags: r, leaflet, gis, rgdal

Morning, afternoon or evening.

I have the following positional data (adjusted from '[Count of sampling points within a grid cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217221/count-of-sampling-points-within-a-grid-cell)')

```
# Demo data 
set.seed(123)
#
lat <- runif(1000, 46.5, 48.5)
lon <- runif(1000, 13,16)
#
pos <- data.frame(lon, lat)
```

Using the following:

```
ggplot(pos, aes(x = lon, y=lat)) + 
  geom_bin2d(bins = 25) +
  stat_bin_2d(aes(label=stat(count)), bins = 25, position="identity") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")+
  theme_void()
```

gives:

[image]

Awesome, but,

I want to do the exact same in leaflet but cannot seem to find a straightforward solution. In reality I have over 5,000,000 data points.

Preferable when running the mouse over the cell, or using leaflets popup functionality, the number of data points for the cell will be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution.. it uses the `sf`-package, as well as tim's amazingly **fast** `leafgl`-package...

**sample data**

```
# Demo data 
set.seed(123)
lat <- runif(1000, 46.5, 48.5)
lon <- runif(1000, 13,16)
pos <- data.frame(lon, lat)
```

**code**

```
library( sf )
library( colourvalues )
#use leafgl for FAST rendering of large sets of polygons..
#devtools::install_github("r-spatial/leafgl")
library( leafgl )
library( leaflet )

#create a spatial object with all points
pos.sf <- st_as_sf( pos, coords = c("lon","lat"), crs = 4326)
#create e grid of polygons (25x25) based on the boundary-box of the points in pos.sf
pos.grid <- st_make_grid( st_as_sfc( st_bbox( pos.sf ) ), n = 25 ) %>% 
  st_cast( "POLYGON" ) %>% st_as_sf()
#add count of points in each grid-polygon, based on an 
# intersection of points with polygons from the grid
pos.grid$count <- lengths( st_intersects( pos.grid, pos.sf ) )
#add color to polygons based on count
cols = colour_values_rgb(pos.grid$count, include_alpha = FALSE) / 255
#draw leaflet
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  leafgl::addGlPolygons( data = pos.grid,
                         weight = 1,
                         fillColor = cols,
                         fillOpacity = 0.8,
                         popup = ~count )
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: Hi Wimpel, many thanks for your comprehensive response. I will get onto it soon. just to acknowledge.

Comment: Hi Wimpel, sorry its taken me a while to get back to it. I report the following error after running line 10: `Error in UseMethod("st_as_sf") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_as_sf' applied to an object of class "c('sfc_POLYGON', 'sfc')"`

Comment: Can you post some sample data where the problem occurs?

Comment: for me, it occurs with the sample data given in the question. confusing!

Comment: strange... just tested.. no error.. only a warning that can be ignored.. Are you running the lastest version of the `sf`-package?

Comment: Okay, I messed around with some of the `sf` package before..... a fresh install and its working! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: might be a bit cheeky, and I am sure I can figure it, but you wouldn't know a quick way within leaflet where `count == 0` it plots transparent / or not at all.

Comment: `pos.grid.filt <- filter(pos.grid, count > 0)` ez

Comment: other approach: you can probably add a column for the cell opacity value, and call it with the fillOpacity-argument...