# r - Grid Coordinates in library(sp) makegrid function

Tags: r, raster, r-sp, rgdal

I am creating a raster over Harris County (Houston, TX) according to example: [How to create a grid of spatial points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787313/how-to-create-a-grid-of-spatial-points).
My code:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

us <- getData('GADM', country = 'US', level = 2)
us$NAME_2
harris = us[us$NAME_1 == "Texas" & (us$NAME_2 == "Harris"),]
```

The example states that the cell size is 0.01 in map units.

```
grid <- makegrid(harris, cellsize = 0.01) # cellsize in map units!
grid <- SpatialPoints(grid, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(harris)))
```

But when I execute "grid" alone:

```
grid
```

It gives "SpatialPoints" x1 and x2:

```
SpatialPoints:
        x1    x2
[1,] -95.96 29.50
[2,] -95.95 29.50
[3,] -95.94 29.50
[4,] -95.93 29.50
[5,] -95.92 29.50
[6,] -95.91 29.50
[7,] -95.90 29.50
[8,] -95.89 29.50
...
...
...
```

**QUESTION: Are these longitudes and latitudes of grid points?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because

```
> proj4string(harris)
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```